Transform Long Data to Table
If I have a data like this:



Column A




1


2


3


4


5


6


7


8



What formula should I use if I want it to look like this in spreadsheet?



Column A
Column B
Column C




1
2
3


4
5
6


7
8




Thank you!
I want to transform my long data into a table view with defined row and column.

You need WRAPROWS() function.
=WRAPROWS(TOROW(A:A,1),3,"")



This =WRAPROWS(A:A,3,"") will also work.
